# what is wrong with the following while loop?

Tags: c, sockets, while-loop, winsock, strtok

I have a **c** **winsock** code section where a client receives a comma delimited stream of file fingerprints as shown below. I need to extract the fingerprints from the stream using `strtok_s()` in a while loop. My problem is **most of the time** the client does not extract the exact number of fingerprints sent from the server, even though the data received(observed by debugging) is exactly what the server sent.
What am I missing here?

```
recv_size = recv(clnt_sock, fp_buf, BUF_LEN, 0);
            received_fp_size += recv_size;
        if (0 != (last_string_len = recv_size % 33))
            strncpy(last_string, &fp_buf[(recv_size - last_string_len)], last_string_len);//
        while (recv_size > 0)
        {
            unique_fp = strtok_s(fp_buf, ",", &strtk);
        k:
            while (unique_fp != NULL)
            {
                memcpy(unique_fp_buf[unique_files_count], unique_fp, 32);
                unique_fp = strtok_s(NULL, ",", &strtk);
                unique_files_count++;

            }


            recv_size = recv(clnt_sock, fp_buf, BUF_LEN, 0);
            received_fp_size += recv_size;
            if (last_string_len > 0)
            {
                unique_fp = strtok_s(fp_buf, ",", &strtk);
                strncat_s(last_string, unique_fp, strlen(unique_fp));
                memcpy(unique_fp, last_string, 32);
                last_string_len = 0;
                goto k;
            }

        }
```

The reason behind the `if (0 != (last_string_len = recv_size % 33))` line is; The server sends a multiple of 33 byte strings(32 for the fingerprint and 1 for the coma demlimiter)

Comment: first suggestion:  do not use the 'goto()` function  Second suggestion: format the code for human readability.

Comment: the question is about a run time problem.  So the posted code must cleanly compile and be executable.  Also include some example input data and the actual output, given that input data and the desired output.

Comment: the posted code contains a 'magic' number.  a 'magic' number is a no with no basis.  I.E.33.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest giving that 'magic' number a meaningful name via a `enum` statement or `#define` statement, then using that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: in the last `if()` block, this line: `memcpy(unique_fp, last_string, 32);` has corrupted the memory where `unique_fp` is pointing.

Comment: the call to `read()` should be similar to: `recv_size = recv(clnt_sock, fp_buf+last_string_len, BUF_LEN-last_string_len, 0);  recv_size += last_string_len;

Comment: your first, second and third comment suggestions are accepted with great appreciation. But I dont get how the memcpy(unique_fp, last_string, 32); corrupts memory, and I dont have a call to read().

Comment: Your correct about 'read()`  I really meant `recv()`

Comment: the memory corruption occurs because the last call to `recv()` began inputting at the beginning of `fp_buf` then `unique_fp` points at the beginning of `fp_buf`  (which is where the call to `recv()` just placed the new input data) then the call to `memcpy()` overlays that new data.  the `answer` also points out this same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you never check that `fp_buf` actually contains a complete token. For instance if the first call only receives 20 bytes, your code will fail by copying a partial fingerprint.

I think another problem is here:

```
memcpy(unique_fp, last_string, 32);
```

Seems you are copying into the receive buffer and therefore overwrites some data that you haven't processed yet. Further, you may overwrite a token.

Maybe you actually wanted:

```
memcpy(unique_fp_buf[unique_files_count], last_string, 32);
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
unique_fp = strtok_s(NULL, ",", &strtk);
unique_files_count++;
```

Besides that I think you are making the code much more complicated than needed. The use of a `goto` kind of tell you that your design is wrong.

Instead of using a `last_string` you could do:

```
1) Call recv
2) Process all complete fingerprints
3) Copy the remainder (i.e. the last partial fingerprint) to the start of `fp_buf`
4) Call `recv` with an offset into `fp_buf`
5) Repeat from step 2 (i.e. use a while loop - don't use goto
```

Step 3 could be something like:

```
recv_size = recv(clnt_sock, fp_buf + length_of_remainder , BUF_LEN -  length_of_remainder, 0);
```

In that way you don't have to handle the `last_string` stuff